# what steps I need to follow if I want to migrate my 1.9.x theme to 2.x

Tags: magento2, theme, migration

I want to migrate my old magento theme to a new Magento 2.x version. What I can do or how I can start with this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 uses new approaches and technologies, it's completely different than Magento 1.x. So Complete Migrataion that includes extensions, theme and database is not possible.

**Regarding Database Migration:**

From M1 to M2, Data Migration is possible using Data Migration tool that includes Products, Customers, orders and System configuration values.

[Data Migration Tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html)

**Regarding Custom Extension Migration:**

It is possible to convert M1 extension into compatible M2 code using Magento Code Migration Toolkit. you can read more about this using below links:

[Extensions and custom code Migration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html#migrate-extensions-code)

[Code Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)

**Regarding Custom Theme Migration:**

As M2 has different file structure and different code pattern that used in Theme Layout and template files also. So it is not possible to migrate Themes directly. So it is not possible to migrate theme in M2. You need to develop theme from scratch or you can use some similar available M2 theme and customize accordingly. you can read more about this using below links:

[Theme and Customizations](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html#migrate-themes-customizations)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I know this already. If you read again my post I ask here for some step by step informations to start with one theme.

Comment: did you checked this tutorial: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html