# How to change a template from magento 1 to magento 2

Tags: magento2

I bought a template ma lavoro but it's not compatible with magento 2. can i do something to make it compatible with magento 2 ??? please any help and thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what steps I need to follow if I want to migrate my 1.9.x theme to 2.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197203/what-steps-i-need-to-follow-if-i-want-to-migrate-my-1-9-x-theme-to-2-x)

Comment: can you please  give me some details : so i have to put the same structure of code and design and skin and others then run toolkit or what i can't understand how to begin  thanks

Comment: Unfortunatly there is no tool(kit) for template migration. There is only a code and a data-migration tool. Also the code structure has changed. I'd either start with comparing M1 template with M2 default Luma theme (to get an idea how things work in M2) or ask for support from the template provider.

Comment: just a question do i have to put the same code in the folder app of my template magento 1 under the app of magento 2 then run this tool or what ??

Comment: Again, there is no tool :( I'v added an link to my answer .... there you should find all information about new structure. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Any reason for removing "accepted answer"?

Comment: just a typo i am sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way to make M1 templates compatible with M2. You have to create or buy a new one.

From [what steps I need to follow if I want to migrate my 1.9.x theme to 2.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197203/what-steps-i-need-to-follow-if-i-want-to-migrate-my-1-9-x-theme-to-2-x/197234#197234)

> As M2 has different file structure and different code pattern that used in Theme Layout and template files also. So it is not possible to migrate Themes directly. So it is not possible to migrate theme in M2. You need to develop theme from scratch or you can use some similar available M2 theme and customize accordingly. you can read more about this using below links:
>
> [Theme and Customizations](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html#migrate-themes-customizations)

---

Fore creating a new template please visit:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html